# How to get an object in object in struts2 JSON

Tags: java, json, hibernate, struts2

I need to get in my JSON a field of an object `Ruolo` contained in another object `Anagrafica`. I tried to includeProperties (`^anagrafiche\[\d+\]\.ruolo.descrizione`) but it doens't work.

**Method in AnagraficaStruts.java (action)**

```
public String AnagraficheJSON(){
    setAnagrafiche(dao.getAnagrafiche());
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Model of Anagrafica**

```
public class Anagrafica {
    private int idAnagrafica;
    private String nome;
    private String cognome;
    private String provincia;
    private String codiceFiscale;
    private Ruolo ruolo;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

**JSON Action in struts.xml**

```
<!-- JSON -->
<action name="listAnagrafiche1" method="AnagraficheJSON"
    class="it.unirc.pjam.Action.AnagraficaStruts">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
        <param name="includeProperties">
            ^anagrafiche\[\d+\]\.idAnagrafica,
            ^anagrafiche\[\d+\]\.nome,
            ^anagrafiche\[\d+\]\.cognome,
            ^anagrafiche\[\d+\]\.provincia,
            ^anagrafiche\[\d+\]\.codicefiscale,
            ^anagrafiche\[\d+\]\.ruolo.descrizione
        </param>
    </result>
</action>
<!-- FINE JSON -->
```

**EDIT**
I need a field of `Ruolo` object, not a field of `Anagrafica`.

Comment: Please do not mark my question as duplicate if you don't understand what i say. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to remove `includeProperties`?

Comment: @AleksandrM yes, i get a lot of null field :(

Comment: Null field where? Remove all params from json result and print object in js.